# Using hping to inject packet into TCP netcat connection

Tags: tcpdump

I have a netcat connection open between a server and a client and i am trying to craft a packet using hping to print the text on the client.

My issue is I am able to craft a very similar packet to what is needed but I am missing the TCP options that are in the packets that are sent from server to the client via netcat.

here is my hping command

```
hping3 -A -y  -M 717766814 -L 3830111434 -N 37033 -w 227 -b  -p 55526 -s 5555 -P 192.168.0.116 -c 1 -d 8 -E task4.txt
```

here is the packet i craft

```
11:16:45.116157 00:a0:98:64:9f:40 > 00:a0:98:36:c8:07, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 62: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37033, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    192.168.0.216.5555 > 192.168.0.116.55526: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5600 (incorrect -> 0x0355), seq 717766814:717766822, ack 3830111434, win 227, length 8
    0x0000:  4500 0030 90a9 4000 4006 2782 c0a8 00d8  E..0..@.@.'.....
    0x0010:  c0a8 0074 15b3 d8e6 2ac8 409e e44a dcca  ...t....*.@..J..
    0x0020:  5018 00e3 5600 0000 4243 4445 4647 410a  P...V...BCDEFGA.
```

the actual packet i need to craft

```
11:16:52.352624 00:a0:98:64:9f:40 > 00:a0:98:36:c8:07, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38493, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.216.5555 > 192.168.0.116.55526: Flags [P.], cksum 0x82cb (incorrect -> 0x0ce8), seq 717766814:717766822, ack 3830111434, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1099353487 ecr 208117467], length 8
    0x0000:  4500 003c 965d 4000 4006 21c2 c0a8 00d8  E..<.]@.@.!.....
    0x0010:  c0a8 0074 15b3 d8e6 2ac8 409e e44a dcca  ...t....*.@..J..
    0x0020:  8018 00e3 82cb 0000 0101 080a 4186 cd8f  ............A...
    0x0030:  0c67 9edb 4142 4344 4546 470a            .g..ABCDEFG.
```

the packets are identical other than missing the options and the checksum

How can i add the options to my crafted packet or is there a another method to getting test to appear on the client using hping?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. If you craft and send a single packet with the same TCP sequence numbers as an already sent packet, the receiving kernel TCP reassembly algorithm will drop this new packet. The crafted packet will never reach the `netcat` server.

Comment: @Gohu yes what you say is true but if you use the correct sequence number and ports you can successfully inject into the stream. I have confirmed this in another lab environment.

Comment: I managed to successfully inject into the Netcat stream in another Lab environment. All you need is the ack number of the last received ack packet in the stream and the ports. I am assuming it has something to do with my NIC on my environment as to why it is not successful.

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, `hping3` does not provide a way to set `TCP` options out-of-the-box.
However, good news is that the `TCP` options are right next to the `TCP` payload in the packet. So you can prepend your data with the TCP options:

1. Instead of just the data, put the TCP options + data in the file you provide to `hping3`:

   ```
   echo "0101080a4186cd8f0c679edb414243444546470a" | python3 -c "import sys, binascii; sys.stdout.buffer.write(binascii.unhexlify(input().strip()))" > /tmp/task4.txt
   ```
2. Send using `hping3`, you will need to change the data size to `20` and set the data offset to `8` ([default data offset is `5` 32 bits words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)) to properly identify the added `TCP` options:

   > ```
   >  -O --tcpoff
   >         Set fake tcp data offset. Normal data offset is tcphdrlen / 4.
   > ```

   ```
   hping3 -A -y  -M 717766814 -L 3830111434 -N 37033 -w 227 -b  -p 55526 -s 5555 -P 192.168.134.161 -c 1 -d 20 -O 8 -E task4.txt
   ```

Resulting crafted packet:

```
08:27:07.956095 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37033, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.134.142.5555 > 192.168.134.161.55526: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5451 (incorrect -> 0x0104), seq 0:8, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1099353487 ecr 208117467], length 8
    0x0000:  4500 003c 90a9 4000 4006 1b92 c0a8 868e  E..<..@.@.......
    0x0010:  c0a8 86a1 15b3 d8e6 2ac8 409e e44a dcca  ........*.@..J..
    0x0020:  8018 00e3 5451 0000 0101 080a 4186 cd8f  ....TQ......A...
    0x0030:  0c67 9edb 4142 4344 4546 470a            .g..ABCDEFG.
```